# Time complexity smallest asymptotic running time

Tags: runtime

what would the time complexity for f(n)=n^3/logn be? And for a double series (2 sums)? I know it is either polynomial or polylog.

Comment: This might be better served on the theoretical computer science stackexchange

Comment: @PeterKlipfel The theoretical computer science stackexchange is for research-level questions only. I doubt they would like this question. It is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: @PeterKlipfel There is however http://cs.stackexchange.com, which is meant for general audience.

Comment: Ah right! I was actually thinking of the cs stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

`f(n) = n^3 / log(n)` is obviously `Θ(n^3/log(n))`, which is also `o(n^3)`, but `ω(n^2)`. Therefore the function does not grow faster than polynomial, but faster than polylogarithmic (Because all polylogarithmic functions grow slower than quadratic and actually slower than any power).

In fact for all `ε > 0`: `f(n) in ω(n^(3-ε))`.

Proofs for all of these statements should be pretty simple.

The second question depends on the sum limits and inner term.

Comment: It was: (sum i=1 to n) (sum j=1 to i) of j

Comment: @user3251244 Please add that and the complexity of the inner term of the sum (probably constant) to your question (see the edit button).